# Changing td to textbox when clicked and changing textbox back to td when user is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, replacewith

I'm looking for a way the user can change a td from table by clicking on it. My current setup is when a user clicks on a td, it should replace the clicked td by a textbox which contains the text from the clicked td. Then when the user clicks outside of it, or presses enter. It should change the textbox back to td.

This is the Table I have:

```
<table class="table" id="tableCompleted">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>D</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jesse</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>David</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the script I have written, the problem I have is that, when a users clicks on a td it replaces all the td's and I havent figured out how to change it back when it loses focus. I tried using a button but that made it even worse. Also the text from the td doesn't get placed inside the textbox.

The script I used for it:

```
$('td').click(function () {
    $('td').replaceWith(function () {
        return '<input type="text" id="modify" "value="' + $('#Text').val() + '" />';
    });
})
```

I Currently have 3 problems with it, Im not sure how to only change the td that is clicked, because all the td don't have a unique id or class. And I'm not sure how to change it back when the user is done changing it. Also It doesn't place the content of the td inside the textbox.

Comment: Replacing the table cell with a textbox would make it invalid. You can't have content inside a table that isn't inside a cell, so you can't predict how different browsers would react. Put the textbox inside the cell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For referring to the clicked element you can use the `this` keyword:

```
$('td').on('click', function() {
    $(this)...
});
```

Also you shouldn't replace the `td` with an `input`, because a `tr`element can't have an `input` child. Instead of it remove the textContent of the `td` and append an `input` to it. Here is one way of implementing this:

```
$('td').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $input = $('<input>', {
        value: $this.text(),
        type: 'text',
        blur: function() {
           $this.text(this.value);
        },
        keyup: function(e) {
           if (e.which === 13) $input.blur();
        }
    }).appendTo( $this.empty() ).focus();
});
```

[Here is a demo using the above snippet.](http://jsfiddle.net/xg0ytjpr/)

You have also a more sensible option: `contentEditable` property.

```
$('td').prop('contentEditable', true);
```

Using the above property browser handles the editing. You can either manually add a `contentEditable` to the target cells in your markup or use JavaScript for modifying the attribute.

Comment: And here's an example using the `contentEditable` attribute https://jsfiddle.net/10u9rgfc/

Answer (score 1):

Pure javascript solution here. And additionaly [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dhu21hy7/1/)
Fight the crime :)

```
(function(){
'use-strict';

var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i=0;i<td.length;i++) {
    td[i].addEventListener('click', change, false);
}

function change() {
    if(this.firstChild.nodeType !== 3) {      
        return;
    }
    var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.value = this.textContent;
    this.removeChild(this.firstChild);
    docFrag.appendChild(input);
    this.appendChild(docFrag);
}
}());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `this`. Here is a working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sachinnambiar/h5g4u1qc/1/).

```
  $('td').click(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith(function () {
        return '<input type="text" id="modify" value="' + $(this).text() + '"> </input>';
    });
})
```

To get it back you can use attach `focusout` on `this`.

Comment: Your example replaces the td with a textbox but it does not fill it with the value of the td, it now displays undefined

Comment: Updated the demo. Please try again.

Comment: Ahh yes, that seems to work, thanks! I tried your advice with focusout on this, but I'm unable to get it working, do you know why? https://jsfiddle.net/t2cyjzh0/

Comment: @fubbe with minimal modification to the code in question, this demo is working.

Comment: This solution creates invalid markup and there is no guarantee that the snippet will work in all browsers.

Comment: This might be what OP asked for, just that what OP asked for is wrong. Check f.e. @Vohuman 's answer instead.